# Xcode Playground: "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

full error message:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

on this line of code 
`var x = isThereInterection(segments: lines)`

here is more context:

```
class segment {

    var v1x:Double
    var v1y:Double
    var v2x:Double
    var v2y:Double
    var slope: Double
    var b: Double

    init(v1x: Double, v1y: Double, v2x: Double, v2y: Double) {
        self.v1x = v1x
        self.v1y = v1y
        self.v2x = v2x
        self.v2y = v2y
        self.slope = (v2y - v1y) / (v2x - v1x) //finding the slope for the line segment
        self.b = v1y - self.slope * v1x //finding the b value for the line function in y = mx + b
    }

}

func isThereInterection(segments: [segment]) -> Bool{
    var isThere:Bool?

    for seg1 in segments {
        for seg2 in segments {
            let leftSide = seg1.slope - seg2.slope
            let rightSide = seg2.b - seg1.b
            let xValue = rightSide/leftSide //this is the x value where the lines would intersect
            if((seg1.v1y...seg1.v2x).contains(xValue) && (seg2.v1x...seg2.v2x).contains(xValue)){ //here we check if the x value of intersection is in range of both line segments
                return true //if it is in range of both line segments, we have an intersection so return true
            }

        }

    }
    return false
}

var seg1 = segment(v1x: 3, v1y: 1, v2x: 1, v2y: 3)
var seg2 = segment(v1x: 1, v1y: 1, v2x: 3, v2y: 3)
var lines = [seg1, seg2]
var x = isThereInterection(segments: lines)
print(x)
```

but it is weird because the code runs fine when I change `seg1` to
`var seg1 = segment(v1x: 1, v1y: 3, v2x: 3, v2y: 1)`
those values should be interchangeable, anyone know what's going on here?

I've tried the same thing on an online swift playground and the same problem persists, while interchanging the values of seg1 works. All I'm trying to do is pass in an array of segments into my helper function.

Comment: just posted it,

Comment: is that because seg1 and seg2 are the same in the first comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem

```
for seg1 in segments {
    for seg2 in segments {
       // At the very first iteration of the loops, seg1 and seg2 are the same
        let leftSide = seg1.slope - seg2.slope
        let rightSide = seg2.b - seg1.b
        let xValue = rightSide/leftSide //this is the x value where the lines would intersect
        if((seg1.v1y...seg1.v2x).contains(xValue) && (seg2.v1x...seg2.v2x).contains(xValue)){ //here we check if the x value of intersection is in range of both line segments
               return true //if it is in range of both line segments, we have an intersection so return true
         }

    }

}
```

If your input array of segments always have two elements, no need to have a loop. If it is not the case you have to do the calculation where `seg1 != seg2`

Comment: the issue is the lowerBound > upperBound, not sure how to fix

Comment: the issue is your xValue which NAN (Not A Number)

Comment: that is not the issue because xValue is equivalent to -nan (as expected) when the numbers are flip flopped, the issue is when v1x = 3 and v2x = 1 it tries to create a range with lower bound = 3 and upper bound = 1

Comment: I can't use stride function to fix

Comment: when seg1 == seg2, leftSide == 0 and rightSide == 0, xValue will be NAN or -NAN. The rule of math says you cannot divide any number by 0 so 0/0 or -0/0 will be a NAN or -NAN. You may do the division only if leftSide !=0. The range is also a possible error. You can check lower bound and upper bound and swap them when upper bound < lower bound

Comment: I put some login in the constructor of segment that forces the smaller x to be v1x, that solved the issue